# Split the query results into more jsp pages

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to split the query results ,ex. list of items in a e-store, into more jsp pages.Therefore i want to create a navigation bar which shows for ex. the first three items in the first page, the seconds three in the second page and so on.How can i solve it?

I want to create something like this:

[image]

I found on the web the Display Tag Library but it shows also the table of items.
I'm only interested in navigation bar
Thanks

Comment: Simple matter of keeping track of an index and passing it around via a link. And making sure you somehow retrieve the same resultset. But it can be done many ways, so this is opinionated/too broad.

Comment: The most important is to keep navigating pages in board range of real values available in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), resp. the `query parameters` to specify, which resultpage you want to display:

```
http://www.example.com/users?page=1
```

Where `page` is the so called query parameter. Query parameters are appended to a URL via `?` for the first one and `&` for each consecutive:

```
http://www.example.com/users?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&page=1
```

The advantage of this technique: *you make the results bookmarkable*. So you could attach the link in to an email and show your friend Bob the first page of the result set.

Comment: Is there anything already done or i want to create it by scratch?

Comment: This could be easily implemented by yourself: each number on your page could be an '<a>' anchor referring to the result page with the appropriate query parameter. Your backend only has to use the information given via the query string to assemble the right data to display.